# How to identify RGBW LED pins?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, pins, led-strip

I have a RGBW LED but I don't know how to identify the negative and the colors pins.

I tried different combinations with an Arduino Uno but it never produce light.

I never used it so I am not sure if its name name RGBW LED.

[image: RWBW LED]

Comment: That's not the kind of LED that even wakes up for less than 50mA, which the Arduino can't even reach.

Comment: try a battery directly across the pins (with a current limiting resistor of course)

Answer (score 2):

Brand Name: LEDGUHON

Model Number:JH-4RGBW14G

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The pin with a + is the anode of one colour. The three next to it are also anodes.

Each anode is connected to one LED. The cathode of that LED is connected to the pin directly opposite the anode.